# Azure SQL Gateways Update

Tags: sql, database, azure-sql-database, gateway

I am fairly new in the database management world and I just received an email from Microsoft Azure warning me that the gateways IP address in my region will change on the 1st of September 2020, which I guess will potentially impact my database.

Therefore I am wondering if I should do something regarding this change knowing that:

- My Azure SQL server has a "Default" Connection Policy
- I have few IP addresses set in my "Firewall Settings"
- I insert data using the SQL connection
- I query data using Power BI Azure SQL connector

Best,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

It means, that if you have applications that connects to the database server via its IP address, or you query (Power BI) the database via its IP address, you will have to update the connection information.

If you access via the hostname of the database, nothing should change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gustav :)
If we connect Power BI to Azure SQL database using the SQL Server Authentification (username + password), we do not need to change anything. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. The change is about the connection, not the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the IP addresses of all gateways on your firewall rules, as shown below:

[image]

Those are the gateways on my region. Please update with the IP addresses Microsoft sent to you.

"To connect to SQL Database or Azure Synapse, you need to allow network traffic to and from all Gateways for the region.". Source Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture#gateway-ip-addresses).